# Check if a string is startwith in an array

Tags: java, string

```
String[] directions = {"UP","DOWN","RIGHT","LEFT"};
String input = "DOWN 123 test";
```

Is there a way to check the input string is **startwith** one value in directions **without using split** input value?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sure - just iterate over all the directions:

```
private static final String[] DIRECTIONS = {"UP","DOWN","RIGHT","LEFT"};

public static String getDirectionPrefix(String input) {
    for (String direction : DIRECTIONS) {
        if (input.startsWith(direction)) {
            return direction;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Or using Java 8's streams:

```
private static final List<String> DIRECTIONS = Arrays.asList("UP","DOWN","RIGHT","LEFT");

public static Optional<String> getDirectionPrefix(String input) {
    return DIRECTIONS.stream().filter(d -> input.startsWith(d)).findFirst();
}
```

Comment: What is performance of this stream vs DIRECTIONS.contains(input.split(" ")[0]) ? because i need to use it in big loop

Comment: @Jerry06: I'd expect the stream to be faster - but really for performance concerns you should have concrete requirements, and then test against them.

Answer (score 1):

**Iterate through the String array** and use `String startsWith` function.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] directions = { "UP", "DOWN", "RIGHT", "LEFT" };
        String input = "DOWN 123 test";

        for (String s : directions) {
            if (input.startsWith(s)) {
                System.out.println("Yes - "+s);
                break;
            } else {
                System.out.println("no - "+s);
            }
        }
    }
```

**output**

```
no - UP
Yes - DOWN
```

Answer (score 1):

In your case you have to iterate over your array and use the `String.startsWith()` method.

```
for(String direction : directions) {
   if(input.startsWith(direction) {
      // Do something
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

please check the code below.

```
        String[] directions = {"UP","DOWN","RIGHT","LEFT"};
String input = "DOWN 123 test";

for(String dir:directions){
    if(input.startsWith(dir)){
        System.out.println("input string starts with:"+dir);
    }
}
```